# How to determine gRPC release feature list?

Tags: grpc

Can i get of list of features added in each gRPC release ? I am working on gRPC c++ 1.0.0  . https://github.com/grpc/proposal details about each checkin not releases .

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The gRPC changelog is published on github: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases